# How to invoke a fully specialized overloaded operator?

Tags: c++11, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

I have a template overload operator defined like this:

```
enum E1 {e1};
enum E2 {e2};
template <typename T, e1> void operator<<(T& t, int i){ t += i;}
template <typename T, e2> void operator<<(T& t, int i){ t -= i;}
double d = 0;
```

It's good if i invoke the operator this way (which looks sucky)

```
  operator<< <double, e1> (d, 3);
```

but syntax error if i invoke it this way:

```
  d << <double, e1> 3;
```

How to rewrite the second form to make it work? Thank you!

Comment: Define your operator in such a way that it is possible and natural to write `d<<3`. If you can't, use a plain old regular function.

Comment: @n.m. I know a plain function would work, but my entire code path uses << to stream out (append) values. I really don't want this one to look differently from the others.

Comment: You don't really have lots of options here.

Comment: It would be relatively easy to make something like this work: `d << add(3)` and `d << sub(3)`

Comment: You could use a short-lived manipulator to solve your issue? `d << E1 << 3 << "unaffected"`. The manipulator would return a wrapped"d" which would apply the formatting to "3" then return the original "d" for the next operation.

Comment: This operator may be called in a iteration of billions of values, so i am not sure if creating a wrapper on each iteration can be my option. I think i''ll need to eliminate the use of E1/E2 on the template specialization to make it.